# How to use trusted contacts as a selection rule for user panel page, drupal commons

Tags: panels

In Drupal Commons, using Panels, I'd like to change the behavior of the user page.

One variant for users to view their own page, and another for viewing other user pages.
Also, I'd like to limit it so that only the trusted contacts of a user can view his/her page.

It is set up using panels, so first I added a variant with a selection `rule: user: compare - User being viewed is not Logged in user`. This works fine.

But how to configure it to limited to trusted contacts of a user. 
The context for  user: user_trusted_contacts is already listed as an option, but I can't use it as a selection rule. There's no option there for "..user is one of".

I'm sure it can be done within panels, thanks for any help.
D

commons-7.x-3.46

Comment: Mind adding the Drupal version and editing the question so title had specific question and also try to concentrate to bringing up one specific issue? From this long elaboration it is not clear what exact question you'd like to ask the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct solution for this.

So as a workaround, I'm using Flags and Rules. Trusted contacts are flagged (explained in "[How to create a rule to flag users when they're approved as a Trusted Contact?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259306)").

Once the flag is there you can then use it as a selection rule in panels.